# How to monitor devices attached to system for mac, windows and linux using Electron

Tags: electron, usb, electron-builder

I am developing an app that contains monitoring devices attached to the system.

Here is the code I have used USB node package.

> const usb = require('usb');
>
> // List all connected USB devices const devices = usb.getDeviceList();
>
> // Print the product name of each device devices.forEach(device => {
> console.log('Product name:', device.deviceDescriptor.iProduct); });

It's working but I need the device name which is coming undefined.

I have tried with device.getStringDescriptor() as well but did not work.

Any alternative for this solution.